# Translating square with shaders on iPhone

Tags: iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to update my (little) knowledge of OpenGL ES 1.1 to 2.0 on the iPhone. The default OpenGL ES Application template for the iPhone draws a square and makes it translate up and down and works fine. Their implementation does the math for the Y value changes on the shader itself which is pretty much useless. So, I've changed the vertext shader to:

```
uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
varying vec4 colorVarying;


void main()
{
    gl_Position = position * mvpMatrix;
    colorVarying = color;
}
```

Which seems to be correct and common (from I've seen in my research). Obviously, I did the necessary changes to the code, like binding the uniform and, to help with the math, I got the sources for the esUtil.h code. On the drawing method, my code looks like this:

```
transY += 0.075f;   

ESMatrix mvp, model, view;
esMatrixLoadIdentity(&view);
esPerspective(&view, 60.0, 320.0/480.0, 1.0, -1.0);

esMatrixLoadIdentity(&model);
esTranslate(&model, sinf(transY), 0.0f, 0.0f);

esMatrixLoadIdentity(&mvp);
esMatrixMultiply(&mvp, &model, &view);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MVPMATRIX], 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat *)&mvp);
```

And that should be working but, unfortunately, what I get is quite different from a simple translation.

[image: Screenshot]

I've restarted the template a few times but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here... Rotating seems to be working as expected, I believe...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to reverse the order of your position transform, as your matrix library is probably working in Column-major order.

```
gl_Position = position * mvpMatrix;
```

=>

```
gl_Position = mvpMatrix * position;
```

Comment: Yes, if you're feeding in a model view matrix that's in the normal configuration for OpenGL, I believe you need to place it first in the multiplication within your vertex shader.  At least, that's how all my shaders work, like the ones in this sample application: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/ShaderExamples.zip

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I now need to figure out the exact math issue here and why some stuff is using columns and other is not. I assumed multiplication (even on a matrix) was commutative.

Comment: A linear algebra text will go over those rules, but you can also get 3D math primer books that will distill the relevant parts of linear algebra for you.  If a text uses 'row-order' you'll transform matrices like v' = vM, in 'column-order' it's v' = Mv.

Comment: This is reversed even in the source code for the official Android OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorial, which, well, is quite a bit of a shame.

Answer (score 1):

unknowingly you have made a camera position change. In opengles camera(global) and object(local) transforms are just inverse.